# Storing global keys/attributes in ionic 2/Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ionic2, hybrid-mobile-app

I have to store 3 values as global variables in my Ionic Application

1. Auth - Base64 Key (String)
2. CSRF Value : Hash coded (String)
3. URL : URL (String)

Reason being, I need to pass the first 2 across all the REST Calls with a legacy application.

I have written a class like below (Typescript Class) and will import in all Classes

```
export class GlobalVars {

    static   auth :String = '';
    static   csrf :String = '';
    static   url :String = '';

  constructor(auth: String, csrf: String, url: String) {
    GlobalVars.auth = auth;
    GlobalVars.csrf = csrf;
    GlobalVars.url = url;
  }

  setMyGlobalVar(auth: String, csrf: String, url: String) {
    GlobalVars.auth = auth;
    GlobalVars.csrf = csrf;
    GlobalVars.url = url;
  }

  getMyGlobalVarAuth() {
    return GlobalVars.auth
  }

  getMyGlobalVarCSRF() {
    return GlobalVars.csrf;
  }

  getMyGlobalVarURL() {
    return GlobalVars.url;
  }

}
```

Is this a good approach? is there a better method?

Comment: You could use Storage 'https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/'.

Comment: Should I Configuring Storage and specify the storage engine ? Can I use it just out of the box?